# PDO fetch all doesnt work when using variable

Tags: php, arrays

I posted my code below, My issue is that when I used the $id variable to grab data from the database only and empty array is returned however when I hard set the value of $id into the execute command as 1 it grabs the data. When $id is echoed the number 1 is shown.

[Image / Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNxkz.png)

```
<?php
            $ids = array();
            foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value){
                if($name[0] == "c"){
                    $id = $name;
                    $id[0] = '';
                    echo("ID: ".$id." for ".$value." orders. <br>");
                    array_push($ids,$id);

                    $userQuery = $db->prepare("
                        SELECT item_id, item_name, cost, descript, stock
                        FROM items
                        WHERE item_id = :idd
                    ");

                    $userQuery->execute(['idd' => 1]);
                    $result = $userQuery->fetchAll();
                    var_dump($result);
                    }
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Obviously, your problem is not with PDO but with $id. Care to check its value, whether it's anywhere near the one you hardcoded ?

Comment: Yeh, When its echoed the value is 1 which is also the same as the hard coded value. Thanks.

Comment: what gets echoed for `$id` in your `echo` statement when that happens?  I am a bit confused because if `name[] == 'c'`, then I don't see how `$id` could be an integer.

Comment: What about if you `var_dump($id);`? What do you get?

Comment: The `[0]` of a string is the first character you know, right?

Comment: Dan Farrell, The c is at the start of the session name however $id[0] = ''; removes the c leaving just a number.

Comment: var_dump($id);? C:\wamp64\www\cart\cart.php:56:string '�1' (length=2)

Comment: That seems to be an issue, I need to find another way to remove the "C"

Comment: Thanks for all your help.